# Get custom product attribute by product-id in Grouped Product

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, simple-product, grouped-products

I want to display `custom product attribute` of simple product on `Grouped-product` in Grouped phtml file `(app\design\frontend\Company\theme\Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml)` but not getting success.

There are few simple products added in grouped product and all simple product have 1 attribute which i want to display on grouped-product-page.

Magento Version: 2.1.8 but I am ok if i got response for any magento 2.1.x version.

Any help would highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the code which you have used to display the custom attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I done with this code:

> $my_attr = $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($_item->getId(),'attribute_code',$_item->getId());

I added this code in `app\design\frontend\Company\theme\Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml`

My custom attribute code: `attribute_code`

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested too in the question.
The problem is that you can use the above code for "default" attributes, but not for custom attributes.

This works:

```
<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php 
         $attribute = $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('price'); 
         $attr_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
         ?> 
        <?php echo $attr_value; ?>
```

But this, not:

```
<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php 
         $attribute = $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('my_custom_attribute'); 
         $attr_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
         ?> 
        <?php echo $attr_value; ?>
```

I think the problem is that $_item  is not a product object.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue: **Magento 2.2.0**. Created couple of custom attributes such as size, marker etc. Added to default set. But when call for display at the frontend, only the default attributes show up (**SKU, Price etc**). Did anyone figure out? 
Here is a part of the code I modified from the grouped.html. By the way, the same code worked well in Magento 1.8.1

```
    <tr>

        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <th class="col cat.no" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Cat. No.') ?></th>
        <th class="col size" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Size') ?></th>
        <th class="col marker" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Marker') ?></th>
        <th class="col price" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Price') ?></th>
        <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
        <?php endif; ?>



    </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getSKU()) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getMarker()) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getPrice()) ?></td>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112084)

Comment: Sorry, first time in my life posting anything here. Not enough credit. But the problem got fixed. Hope other people find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

**=> You have to hard code your custom attributes into file at line 211:**

> vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php

```
       )->addAttributeToSelect(
            ['name', 'size', 'marker', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
```

In my case it's the 'size" and 'marker"
Please refer to:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12258